Using LocalStack and Serverless Framework in a K8s cluster
I'm trying to deploy and use LocalStack and Serverless Framework in a Kubernetes environment. But I'm unable to get the Serverless Framework to communicate with the LocalStack service. Here's what I did:
Installed Serverless Framework and the LocalStack plugin for it in a container.
npm install -g serverless@3.39.0
npm install --save-dev serverless-localstack

Installed the LocalStack helm chart:
cat << EOF > /tmp/values.yaml
        startServices: "lambda,apigateway"
        service:
          type: ClusterIP
        enableStartupScripts: true
        startupScriptContent: |
          echo "Starting LocalStack for lambda and API Gateway..."
        EOF

helm upgrade --install localstack https://github.com/localstack/helm-charts/releases/download/localstack-0.6.1/localstack-0.6.1.tgz -f /tmp/values.yaml

Create the variables required by LocalStack:
export AWS_REGION=us-west-1
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=test
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=test

Create the AWS_ENDPOINT_URL required by the plugin:
export AWS_ENDPOINT_URL=http://localstack:4566

But then when I run: serverless deploy --stage local it gives the following error:
Skip plugin function AwsDeploy.extendedValidate (lambda.mountCode flag is enabled)
× Stack aws-python-http-api-project-loom-local failed to deploy (27s)
Environment: linux, node 18.20.4, framework 3.39.0, plugin 7.2.3, SDK 4.5.1
Credentials: Local, environment variables
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
Error:
Inaccessible host: `localstack' at port `undefined'. This service may not be available in the `***' region.
 x  Error deploying application: error executing command 'Deploy Serverless application to LocalStack': exit status 1

I verfied that the K8s service called localstack does get created when I install the Helm chart but the from what I understand from the error Serverless Framework isn't picking up the port 4566 that I specified. Can someone help me out how I fix/debug this?
This is what my serverless.yaml looks like:
service: aws-python-http-api-project-loom
frameworkVersion: "3"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.9
  region: us-west-1

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: /
          method: get

plugins:
  - serverless-localstack

custom:
  localstack:
    stages:
      - local
    host: http://localstack
    edgePort: 4566
    lambda:
      mountCode: True

